# the orderby query does not work for custom fields even with meta query

Tags: wordpress

I have written the following query to fetch a list and want to show the list of names in ascending order.

i was earlier trying to pass meta_key and meta_value as arguments but it wouldnt give the sorting correctly.

after trying **meta_query** i am still stuck with the same problem.
let me know how i can go about it thanks.

```
$connected = new WP_Query( array(

                    'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',

                    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),

                    'nopaging' => true,

                    'post_type' => 'attorney',

                    'attorney_category'=> 'partner',

                    'post_status' => 'publish',

                    'posts_per_page' => -1,

                    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,

                    'orderby' => 'order_clause',

                    'order' => 'ASC',

                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'order_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'Last name',
                          )
                        )
                    ) );
```

The following is the error i get when i print the query result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about the previous solution, I was looking at the **meta_query** directly without realizing your actual intention.

So to wrap it up, you're trying to list all the names in ascending order. This can be done without using the **meta_query**

I'm not sure about the `Last name` as the property-name stored in your database. If you're still having trouble try renaming the property that are stored in your database as `last_name` or `lastname`. As a rule of thump avoid naming a property that contains a *Whitespace*.

So the updated solution:

- Remove the **meta_query** item in the array.
- Update the `orderby` value to the `Last name`

Your `WP_Query` initialization as follows:

```
$connected = new WP_Query( array(

    'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
    'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post_type' => 'attorney',
    'attorney_category'=> 'partner',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,

    'orderby' => 'Last name', // Again I'm not sure about this `Last name` as an property-name
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: but in the database the table has been named Last name. so meta_value has to be Last name right??

Comment: what is the error?? sorry i couldnt see it as i have written this code watching wordpress docs.

Comment: i want the entire list of values and not a specific one.
so i still need to add the 'value' key in the meta_query??